# view doc , docx , xls ,xlsx ... files on windows phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any control or lib for windows phone 7.5 to view ( not edit ) doc , docx , xls ,xlsx ... and all the other office documents?
I know I can try to send the docs to office on the phone , but I want an in app solution.

thank you!